# how to upload and display image in JFrame using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I need to upload and display an image selected with the `JFileChooser` (i.e the user wants to set his/her profile picture) in a `JFrame`.. How should I do it?

Here is my code for choosing the file:

```
private void UploadImageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int returnVal = fileChosser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChosser.getSelectedFile();
        // What to do with the file
        // I want code for this part
        try {
            //code that might create an exception 
        } 
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have named your method `UploadImageActionPerformed`: please read the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Method names should be written with a lower character at the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it myself. I chose an image and displayed in a `JLabel`.

Here is My code:

```
private void uploadImageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
    filechooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Your File");
    filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    // below code selects the file 
    int returnval = filechooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            // display the image in a Jlabel
            bi = ImageIO.read(file);
            jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        } catch(IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); // todo: implement proper error handeling
        }
        this.pack();
    }
}
```