# how can i upload an image on my system using jFilechoose?

Tags: java, user-interface, oop, jlabel, jfilechooser

So basically my problem is how to upload an image on my system (ticketing system). I am new to GUI.

Someone told me that it can be done by JFileChooser (to search the image) and JLabel (the handler of the image) but if you guys know other options please let me know. I badly need this. This is the only missing part for my final project.

Comment: [Why you think JFileChooser is not that good](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and looking out other options

Comment: What do you mean by uploading on your system ? Do you want to be able to choose an image on your C:/ , for example, and display it on a JLabel using it as an icone ?

Comment: yes that's kinda it. but will i be able to save that on my database ? i mean the image that i uploaded? well to make it simple. just think of it this way it's like uploading a profile picture on facebook. that's basically what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your comment i now see what you want to do.
You will need to do the following steps :

- Use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to obtain the desired img (don't forget to put a mask to only see the *.jpeg for example)
- Setting the [icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) of a JLabel with the path, obtained via the JFileChooser, of the image (It's more user friendly to see what img you are going to save :))
- Now that you have the path of the image what you need to do is to read that image and 'convert' it into an `byte[]`
- Now that you have the bytes of your image save it into your database (via a [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) for example)

I hope it's helps you or at least gives you one way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516939/how-to-upload-and-display-image-in-jframe-using-jfilechooser) for an example of how to upload and display an image using JFileChooser.